# Is it possible to use a View inside a RadioButton?

Tags: android

I'm trying to create a Fragment where the user can select the line width from 4 options. When they select one of the widths, I set the background with a blue highlight. Is it possible to use a `radio group` with `views` inside `radio buttons`?

[image]

Currently this is how I'm doing it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Checkbox test"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/background_selected_width_outline"
        android:layout_margin="16dp">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:background="@color/colorBlack"
            android:layout_margin="32dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/colorBlack"
        android:layout_margin="32dp"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not possible . Check the source code of `RadioGroup` it directly bypass the add View call to `super` if `if (child instanceof RadioButton)` is false . You can create a Custom group to act it like `RadioGroup` by extending it from `LinearLayout`.